# SWT Table with SWT.VIRTUAL raises StackOverflowError

Tags: java, windows-7, swt, stack-overflow

After recently installing Windows 7 Professional, I'm getting a strange problem removing a TableItem from a populated Table in SWT. It is specific to Windows 7 and to the `SWT.VIRTUAL` style constant for the table.

Consider the following code:

```
table = new Table(parent, SWT.VIRTUAL | Skin.SCROLL_STYLE |
                          SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
item.setText("Table item");
table.remove(0);
```

This causes a StackOverflowError as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2312)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5520)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4602)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3106)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.wmNotifyChild(Table.java:6319)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:4877)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1757)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:4507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4000)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4602)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at ...
```

As shown above, the stack cycles from the Display's `windowProc` call to the OS' `CallWindowProcW`; this leads me to suspect that it has something to do with the Windows 7-specific implementation of SWT. The stack trace eventually originates from the `table.remove(0)` line.

Testing under Vista, XP or Mac OS X gives no problems.

Removing the `SWT.VIRTUAL` style constant resolves the problem, but doesn't allow for custom objects in the table.

It would seem that this is a SWT bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Report it to the SWT guys with a test case.

Comment: It is a bug; I've reported it to Eclipse, and it's already been fixed in the HEAD. See the report here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=142593

Answer (score 0):

Try item.dispose() instead?

Comment: That's actually what I had before I tried fixing it with `table.remove(0)`. The bug was confirmed and fixed in the current SWT release.